# Adding children to VBox in JavaFX using a for loop

Tags: java, loops, vbox

I'm making a mortgage calculator using JavaFX for a school project. The user will input their interest rate, loan amount, and loan term. It then calculates monthly payments, total payments, and overpayments. I made one using a Scanner and outputting with System.out, but now I need to make it as a GUI using JavaFX. I have most of it completed, but I've run into an issue with my for loops. The program will display 1% above and below what the user entered in increments of 0.005 so I wanted to utilize a for loop as I did in the previous version. I have made a VBox display the percentages line after line, and the plan was to add the different percentages using a for loop but I keep getting errors.

```
oneBelowIR = annualIR - 0.01;

interestText = new Text("Interest Rate");
        interestText.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
        VBox iRateBox = new VBox();
        iRateBox.getChildren().add(interestText);
        grid.add(iRateBox, 60, 0);

for (int i=0;i<=4;i++) {
    iRate.getChildren().add(oneBelowIR);
}
```

I keep getting "double cannot be converted to node." And I've also tried `iRate.getChildren().add(Double.toString(oneBelowIR);` and that gave me "String cannot be converted to node"

Can anyone help me figure this out? I've to google both errors and can't get anything that is like what I'm dealing with. Googling "Adding VBox children with for loop" does not present any good finds either.

Here is the function that oneBelowIR comes from.

```
public void Calculate(ActionEvent event) {
    // Convert the text from textfields to double and int
    annualIR = Double.parseDouble(irText.getText()) / 100;
    mortAmt = Double.parseDouble(loanAmtText.getText());
    numOfYears = Integer.parseInt(loanTermText.getText());

    oneBelowIR = annualIR - 0.01;
```

}

This isn't all of the function but just trying to show where oneBelowIR comes from

Comment: maybe you want to do something like this: iRate.getChildren().add(new Text("" + oneBelowIR));

Comment: More a little hint: Is the iRate some instance of an javafx.scene.layout.Pane, like GridPane, VBox, etc. and oneBelowIR a double? If yes, this doesn't work, you can only add an instance of javafx.scene.Node to the Pane over the [Pane].getChildren.add([Node]) call

Comment: Yes iRate is a VBox, wish there was a way to do it like this. I really like VBox as I don't have to do trial and error with coordinates to make sure everything lines up.

Comment: have you tried what i wrote?

Comment: Yea it gave the same error "double can't be converted to Node"

Comment: Any recommendations on how I can achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You did not try Ofek solution. If you did it is impossible to get the same error.